# Add a column with a reference from composite primary key to hierachical table

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a hierarchical table with a composite primary key. However I also want a ParentNode to be set following the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#BKMK_EnforcingTrees). However since I have a composite PK from UserID and NodeID, I can't get this to work without explicitly adding the constraint afterwards.

This is the relevant query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderStatus](
    [NodeID] HIERARCHYID NOT NULL,
    [StatusID] INT UNIQUE IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
    [Level] AS [NodeID].GetLevel(),
    [ParentID] AS [NodeID].GetAncestor(1) PERSISTED REFERENCES [dbo].[OrderStatus](UserID, NodeID),
    [Reason] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Info] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [SignatureRequired] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [BarcodeRequired] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [PhotoRequired] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [UserID] INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (UserID, NodeID)
)
GO

CREATE INDEX [OrderStatus_BreadthFirst] ON [OrderStatus](Level, NodeID)
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrderStatus] (NodeID, Reason, UserID)
VALUES
('/', 'Root', 1),
('/0/', 'Fulfilled', 1),
('/1/', 'Partially fulfilled', 1),
('/2/', 'Not fulfilled', 1)
```

Now basically I have two questions as to what would be possible:

1. Would setting `[ParentID] AS [NodeID].GetAncestor(1) PERSISTED REFERENCES [dbo].[OrderStatus](UserID, NodeID)` somehow be possible?
   And if it isn't,
2. How can I work around `GetAncestor(1)` with a composite PK?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the point of the foreign key that references itself?

Comment: @TabAlleman Desperation mixed with exhaustion I guess _facepalm_ haha I have no idea how that happened to be honest. I guess I tried to work around the Reference issue by doing something that absolutely doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @TabAlleman Sorry about that. I was trying to work around the situation that's now in the edited question above. I don't need the constraint in itself, I need to somehow get the ParentNode again but the composite primary key is making things hard I guess